# Bootstrap 5.3 mixins and vars in components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-5

I am using Vue 3 with Vite and no Webpack, just npm.

I am trying to use mixins and vars inside my components but am getting errors:

*Error: Undefined mixin.
╷
31 │             @include rfs(1.5rem);*

Is this possible? Should I use Webpack to get this working?

This is my vite.config.js file:

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'
import { resolve, dirname } from 'node:path'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import VueI18nPlugin from '@intlify/unplugin-vue-i18n/vite'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    VueI18nPlugin({
      include: resolve(dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url)), './src/i18n/translations/**'),
    })
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: [
      ".mjs",
      ".js",
      ".ts",
      ".jsx",
      ".tsx",
      ".json",
      ".vue",
      ".scss",
    ],
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url)),
      '~bootstrap': 'bootstrap'
    },
  },
  server: {
    port: 8090,
  },
})
```

And here is my assets/scss/style.scss:

```
@import "_variables.scss";

@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_functions.scss";
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_variables.scss";
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_maps.scss";
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_mixins.scss";
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_utilities.scss";
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_helpers.scss";
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/utilities/_api.scss";


$custom-colors: (
  "tertiary": $purple
);

$theme-colors: map-merge($theme-colors, $custom-colors);

.bg-tertiary{background-color: var(--bs-purple);};

@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";

@import "_mixins.scss";
@import "_global.scss";
@import "_utilities.scss";

@import "_dropdowns.scss";
@import "_navs.scss";
@import "_buttons.scss";
@import "_cards.scss";
@import "_login.scss";
@import "_error.scss";
@import "_footer.scss";
@import "_badges.scss";
@import "_pagination.scss";
@import "_tabs.scss";
@import "_tables.scss";
@import "_dropfile.scss";
```

The styles.scss file is included in the main.js file, like so:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { createPinia } from 'pinia'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import i18n from './i18n'
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle';

import BootstrapIcon from '@dvuckovic/vue3-bootstrap-icons';
import Spinner from '@/components/Spinner'
import "@/assets/scss/styles.scss";

const pinia = createPinia()
const app = createApp(App)

app.use(pinia)
app.use(i18n)
app.use(router)

app.component('BootstrapIcon', BootstrapIcon);
app.component('Spinner', Spinner)
app.mount('#app')
```